# batch file copies folder and pastes it the location where the batch file is run from

Tags: batch-file, copy, paste

This is a batch based skill required program
That is used to backup data

The batch file is stored on a removable device like:

Pendrive
Flashdrive 
SDCard (memory card)

When the batch file is executed it must collect a folder found at location "X"

D:/music

All data in this folder must be copied to the location of where the batch file is

If the batch file is located at any of these points

E:/
F:/
G:/ 
Even 
Z:/

The batch operation should know where it is located and copy the music folder and paste it where the batch file is run from

My device when connected via USB changes sometimes
(E:/music) 
(F:/music)
Batch file root folder

PC 
E:/music (fixed location)

Code 
Batch copies all content in E:/music 
Batch pastes all Content to drive E:/ or F:/ 
Without errors 
Batch file must know where it is

Can you please help me with this its very useful and resourceful because I can save content to my device and its very small

Comment: What is? What are you asking for? I'm sorry, but I didn't understand a thing you wrote.

Comment: @Tarec: He's giving some specifications and is looking for someone to do the work for him.

Comment: @tarec its not to complex the statement sorry how I ask my head thinks this way

Comment: @stephan - I know the basics the problem lies in the location when the drive letter changers that I need

Comment: `%~dp0` gives you the path where your batfile is located.

Comment: Thank you Stephan that's the "%~dp0" was all I needed to complete the batch file thank you for that :D

Answer (score 0):

This simple batch file does the job:

```
@echo off
if exist "D:\music\*" (
   echo Deleting %~d0\music ...
   rd /S /Q "%~d0\music" 2>nul
   echo Copying D:\music to %~d0\music ...
   xcopy  "D:\music\*" "%~d0\music" /S /E /C /I /Q /H /K
   echo Folder D:\music copied to drive %~d0
   pause
)
```

I used the information printed by running in a command prompt window the commands:

- `cmd /?` ... outputs help for command **CMD** which is the interpreter of batch files, and listing also internal commands of the command line interpreter **CMD**.
- `for /?` ... outputs help for command **FOR** with information about `~d` to get drive from a string like argument 0 of the batch file referenced by `%0` which is the name of the batch file with path.
- `rd /?` ... outputs help for command **RD** with information how to silently delete an entire directory tree.
- `xcopy /?` ... outputs help for command **XCOPY** with information how to silently copy an entire directory tree.

The command **RD** is used to first remove the target directory on removable media before copying the files from source directory to avoid a mixture of new and old folders and files.

The command **XCOPY** is used to copy the entire directory tree of `D:\music` to the removable media nearly completely silent. Just the total number of copied files is output which I think is good to see.

Comment: I wouldve added /z so that if it does fail it would resume

Comment: No, I would not use option `/Z` on `xcopy` command for copying files from hard disk to a removable media. You should not unplug the SDCard while the copying process is active as this can result in damaged files on memory card. And holding the copy process until the memory card is plugged in again to resume is not advisable. Read [Xcopy](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx) documentation of Microsoft to understand for which purpose `/z` is really designed for (copying files to a server in a network).